# Calculate GPS bearing if POI falls within the threshold

Tags: android, gps, geometry, geospatial

The use case that I am doing is to show POI's within the current position based on current bearing. For example if I am heading North I will not show POI's from South but only show POI's according to the bearing within the threshold.

[image: Representation]

[image: Degrees]

Comment: So you need to find difference of two bearings (angles)?

Comment: yes, something like that. I need to check the POI is within the range of x1,x2.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with 360/0 transition, you can use next condition accounting for periodicity

```
if (Cos(Bearing) * Cos(POI) + Sin(Bearing) * Sin(POI) > Cos(Threshold)) then
   POI direction lies in range Bearing +- Threshold
```

Comment: I used this calculation to get the bearing and in degrees already.

`double degrees = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
double fValue = degrees < 0d ? (degrees +=360d) : degrees;` 

should I do some conversions before doing the calculations?

Comment: Yes, you should transform degrees to radians. But are you sure that `atan2(y, x)` works well for geographic coordinates?

Comment: Thanks @MBo .Yes It is working as it is. The angle is expressed in degrees normalized to [0, 360] deg. and North referencing 360 deg. I added an image.

Comment: I tried your formula sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't. I will post my solution but I am still working on how to simplify it. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show an example of data that produces wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for now. While working to simplify it. Suggestions are welcome.

```
public static boolean isBearingWithinRange(double heading, double alertHeading, double threshold) {
    boolean status = false;
    double leftThresholdMin = heading - threshold;
    double leftThresholdMax = FULL_CIRCLE;
    double rightThresholdMin = 0.0d;
    double rightThresholdMax = 0.0d;

    double total = heading + threshold;

    if(total > FULL_CIRCLE) {
        rightThresholdMax = threshold - (FULL_CIRCLE - heading);

        if((alertHeading >= leftThresholdMin && alertHeading <= leftThresholdMax) ||
                (alertHeading >= rightThresholdMin && alertHeading <= rightThresholdMax)) {
            status =  true;
        }

    } else if(heading < threshold) {
        double diff =  (threshold - heading);
        leftThresholdMin = FULL_CIRCLE - diff;
        rightThresholdMax = threshold + heading;

        if((alertHeading >= leftThresholdMin && alertHeading <= leftThresholdMax) ||
        (alertHeading >= rightThresholdMin && alertHeading <= rightThresholdMax)) {
            status =  true;
        }

    } else {
        rightThresholdMax = heading + threshold;

        if(alertHeading >= leftThresholdMin && alertHeading <= rightThresholdMax) {
            status = true;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```